# How execute a playbook within Vagrantfile with a certain condition?

Tags: ansible, vagrant

Im struggling with this Vagrantfile. My goal is to set up two virtual machines using Vagrant technology and also utilize Ansible to deploy a certain task in each machine after they had been created.
But how can execute provision with ansible after the two machines had been created successfuly?

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# variables
BOX_NAME = "debian/buster64"
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_CONTROLLER = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_VAGRANT = "~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
PUBLIC_KEY_PATH_CONTROLLER = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
AUTHORIZED_KEYS_PATH = "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# configuracion general
  config.vm.box = BOX_NAME
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = [PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_CONTROLLER, PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_VAGRANT]
  config.vm.provision "file", source: PUBLIC_KEY_PATH_CONTROLLER, destination: AUTHORIZED_KEYS_PATH
  config.vm.synced_folder "./shared", "/vagrant" 
# configuracion nodo 1
  config.vm.define "nodo_uno" do |nodo|
    nodo.vm.hostname = "nodo1"
    nodo.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
    nodo.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "nodo1(50.10)"
      vb.memory = 512
      vb.cpus = 1
    end
  end
# configuracion nodo 2
  config.vm.define "nodo_dos" do |nodo|
    nodo.vm.hostname = "nodo2"
    nodo.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.20"
    nodo.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "nodo2(50.20)"
      vb.memory = 512
      vb.cpus = 1
    end
  end


#  if nodo = "nodo_dos" 
   config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
   # ansible.groups = {
   #   "nodo_uno" => ["nodos"],
   #   "nodo_dos" => ["nodos"]
   # }
    ansible.inventory_path = "./hosts"
    ansible.limit = "nodos"
    ansible.playbook = "grupos_usuarios.yml"
    ansible.become = true
   end
end
```

**nodos** is a group that involves **nodo_uno** and **nodo_dos**
so when I run vagrant up, ansible throws me an error because of noo2 has not been created yet. so it can't provision it.
I know I can use "vagrant up --no-provision" and then "vagant provision" but what I want is to avoid this system and use some conditional statement in my vagrantfile that triggers my playbook once node2 had been successfuly set up. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your commented `if` statement is how [the fine manual](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible#ansible-parallel-execution) says to fix that problem -- wait until all hosts are up and run provision `limit = "all"`; does your playbook need access to both hosts?

Comment: yes my playbook needs acces to both hosts. thats why ansible throws me an error. because it tryes to provision a node that does not exist  (nodo_dos). I have tried to use the if conditional but i dont know how to apply it on this specific vagrantfile

Comment: Ever get this to work ?